# Javascript Onclick funcionar multiplas vezes

Tags: javascript

preciso fazer uma border aparecer e sumir sempre que clicar. Nao posso usar jQuery nem eventlist. 
Sei que devo usar IF mas nao sei como. O que consigo ate agora eh clicar e fazer ela aparecer. Deve ser ao redor dos paragrafos. 
Agradeco ajuda

```
 var elements = document.getElementsByTagName("p");
for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++){
    elements[i].onclick=function(){
    this.style.border="dashed black 1px";

}
```

}

Comment: Ela deve sumir quando? Um determinado tempo depois de aparecer?

Answer (score 0):

É só verificar se o elemento possui a borda

```
if (this.style.border) {
    this.style.border="";
} else {
    this.style.border="dashed black 1px";
}
```

#### Exemplo

```js
var elements = document.getElementsByTagName("p");
for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++){
    elements[i].onclick=function(){
      if (this.style.border) {
        this.style.border="";
      } else {
        this.style.border="dashed black 1px";
      }
    }

}
```

```html
<p>Elemento</p>
<p>Elemento</p>
<p>Elemento</p>
<p>Elemento</p>
<p>Elemento</p>
<p>Elemento</p>
<p>Elemento</p>
<p>Elemento</p>
<p>Elemento</p>
<p>Elemento</p>
<p>Elemento</p>
```

Comment: Obrigada!!! Perfeito!

Comment: Mais recomendo usar a resposta do @Oeslei.

Answer (score 0):

Utilize css para exibir a borda. Assim, basta utilizar o método `toggle` para adicionar / remover a classe responsável por adicionar a borda.

No JS:

```
this.classList.toggle('com-borda');
```

No CSS:

```
.com-borda {
    border: dashed black 1px;
}
```